# How i can Run PageTurner project from github?

Tags: java, android

I am new android developer.I want to run the project of Page Turner(from git-hub project).I can't run this project.Only one error show here.This error are "The type org.htmlcleaner.TagNode cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files".I also added with this project

1)ActionBarSherlock library project.

2)daisy-htmlcleaner-1.4.1.jar file.

3)epublib-core-latest.jar file.

4)htmlspanner-0.3-SNAPSHOT.jar file.

5) maven-site-1.0-site.jar file.

Please help to me,how i can run this project without this error.

Answer (score 0):

Well, looking at the error message, it seems that you have the wrong version of htmlcleaner.

Are you using Maven to build PageTurner? That should automatically download the correct dependencies for you.

If you're trying to build PageTurner in Eclipse, take a look at the screencast I did: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jhSvwpwPFoY